# propbem the mysqlconnection when using public variable in class level

Tags: c#, mysql

I have c# class that make me to connect the database and make some operations on it.

```
#region Var
        private readonly string DbPath;
        public MySqlConnection DbConn;

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public ClsDb()
        {
            DbPath = "SERVER= " + Db.Default.ServerName + "; " +
                    "DATABASE= " + Db.Default.DbName + "; " +
                    "UID= " + Db.Default.UserName + "; " +
                    "PWD= " + Db.Default.UserPass + "; " +
                    "PORT= " + Db.Default.ThePort+"; sslmode=none";
            DbConn = new MySqlConnection(DbPath);
        }
        #endregion
```

as you see I declared (mysqlconnection) :

```
DbConn = new MySqlConnection(DbPath);
```

so after that I check the connection:

```
public bool CheckConn()
{
    try
    {
        if (DbConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            DbConn.Close();
        }

        if (DbConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            DbConn.Open();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Msgs.Default.ConnErr,
                          Settings.Default.ComName,
                          MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                          MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
        return false;
    }

}
```

and after that I'm trying to execute SQL statement by method:

```
public void RunSql(string xSql, MySqlParameter[] xPar)
        {
            //...
            MySqlCommand xCmd = new MySqlCommand(xSql, DbConn);

            // ....
            if (xPar != null)
            {
                xCmd.Parameters.AddRange(xPar);
            }

            //...
            xCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

but it gives me the following error:

> "Connection must be valid and open."

when I checked the code by the breakpoints I got that everything is ok and it opens the connection very well but when it execute (public void RunSql) and exactly on the line:

```
MySqlCommand xCmd = new MySqlCommand(xSql, DbConn);
```

[image]

when I tried to solve it I changed (public MySqlConnection DbConn) to (public Static MySqlConnection DbConn) and it worked but I needed to know why that happened although I declared the variable as public?? and why it worked when I changed to Static??

Comment: There are *thousands* of posts here on the correct way to create, use and dispose of connections and other DB and IDisposable objects.  Not to mention the wellspring of valid information on MS-Docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using my own class for this. In it isn't necessary to close the connection because uses the 'using'.

The class:

Connection (return open connection)

```
public static MySqlConnection GetConn()
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnString);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (MySqlException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        
        return conn;
    }
```

Insert Commands (accept params)

```
public static int InsertSqlCommand(string db, params (string param, object value)[] listParams)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection conn = GetConn())
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(db, conn))
            {
                
                foreach ((string dbLocal, object incremento) in listParams)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(dbLocal, incremento);
                

                int linhasAfetadas = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                return linhasAfetadas;
            }
        }
    }
```

Select Command (accept params)

```
 public static DataTable SelectSqlCommand(string db, params (string param, object value)[] listParams)
    {
        DataTable dttoken = new DataTable();

        using (MySqlConnection conn = GetConn())
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(db, conn))
            {
                
                foreach ((string dbLocal, object incremento) in listParams)
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(dbLocal, incremento);
                

                using (MySqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    sqlDA.Fill(dttoken);
                    return dttoken;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks but what's mean             throw;